# How does Excel's FREQUENCY function work?

Tags: excel, vba

With the following function:

```
=FREQUENCY(C2:C724,D2:D37)
```

The second parameter is the `BIN`

What I don't understand is why Excel would increment the `BIN` for the rest of your values. The BIN does not change! It stays the same bin. Yet when I paste the formula for all my values it does this:

```
=FREQUENCY(C2:C724,D2:D37)
=FREQUENCY(C2:C724,D3:D38)
=FREQUENCY(C2:C724,D4:D39)
```

The last column is what was generated (and this is correct but it does not make sense!!)

```
Etoh        bin
15.9        20        0
14.6        19        0
14.1        18        0
13.9        17        0
13.3        16        0
13.3        15        0
13.2        14        1
12.6        13        2
12.1        12        3
11.8        11        6
11.5        10        4
11.2         9        4
11           8        8
10.5         7       10
10.3         6       26
10.3         5       27
10.2         4       40
10.1         3       89
9.8          2      151
9.7          1      205
9.5          0      102
9.1         -1       17
8.9         -2        7
8.3         -3        3
8.1         -4        2
8.1         -5        0
7.9         -6        3
7.6         -7        2
7.5         -8        2
7.5         -9        1
7.5        -10        1
7.4        -11        0
7.2        -12        0
7.1        -13        1
7.0        -14        0
7.0        -15        0
6.8
6.7
6.6
6.5
6.4
6.2
6.2
6.1
6.0
5.9
5.8
5.8
5.7
5.7
5.7
5.5
5.5
5.5
5.4
5.3
5.3
5.3
5.3
5.3
5.3
5.3
5.2
5.2
5.2
5.1
5.1
5.1
5.1
5.1
5.0
5.0
5.0
5.0
5.0
4.9
4.9
4.8
4.8
4.8
4.7
4.7
4.6
4.6
4.6
4.5
4.5
4.5
4.5
4.4
4.3
4.1
4.1
4.1
4.1
4.1
4.1
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
3.9
3.9
3.9
3.9
3.9
3.8
3.8
3.7
3.6
3.6
3.6
3.6
3.6
3.5
3.5
3.4
3.4
3.4
3.4
3.3
3.3
3.3
3.3
3.2
3.2
3.2
3.2
3.2
3.2
3.1
3.1
3.1
3.1
3.1
3.1
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
3.0
2.9
2.9
2.9
2.8
2.8
2.8
2.8
2.8
2.8
2.8
2.8
2.7
2.7
2.7
2.7
2.7
2.7
2.7
2.7
2.6
2.6
2.6
2.6
2.6
2.6
2.6
2.6
2.6
2.5
2.5
2.5
2.5
2.5
2.4
2.4
2.4
2.4
2.4
2.4
2.4
2.4
2.3
2.3
2.3
2.3
2.3
2.3
2.3
2.3
2.3
2.3
2.3
2.3
2.2
2.2
2.2
2.2
2.2
2.2
2.2
2.2
2.2
2.2
2.2
2.2
2.1
2.1
2.1
2.1
2.1
2.1
2.1
2.1
2.1
2.1
2.1
2.1
2.1
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
2.0
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.9
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.8
1.7
1.7
1.7
1.7
1.7
1.7
1.7
1.6
1.6
1.6
1.6
1.6
1.6
1.6
1.6
1.6
1.6
1.6
1.6
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.5
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.4
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.3
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.2
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.1
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.9
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.7
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.6
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.5
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.4
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.3
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.2
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.2
-0.2
-0.2
-0.2
-0.2
-0.2
-0.2
-0.2
-0.2
-0.2
-0.2
-0.3
-0.3
-0.3
-0.3
-0.3
-0.3
-0.3
-0.3
-0.3
-0.3
-0.4
-0.4
-0.4
-0.4
-0.4
-0.4
-0.4
-0.4
-0.4
-0.4
-0.4
-0.5
-0.5
-0.5
-0.5
-0.5
-0.5
-0.6
-0.6
-0.6
-0.6
-0.6
-0.6
-0.7
-0.7
-0.7
-0.7
-0.7
-0.7
-0.7
-0.7
-0.8
-0.8
-0.8
-0.8
-0.8
-0.8
-0.8
-0.8
-0.9
-0.9
-0.9
-0.9
-0.9
-0.9
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.1
-1.1
-1.2
-1.2
-1.2
-1.3
-1.3
-1.7
-1.8
-1.9
-1.9
-2.1
-2.2
-2.4
-2.4
-2.5
-2.5
-2.6
-3.0
-3.2
-3.7
-4.6
-4.6
-6.1
-6.3
-6.3
-7.0
-7.8
-8.1
-8.5
-9.0
-10.2
-13.2
```

If I do as both of you suggested with the $, I am getting the WRONG results:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit of keyboarding to make it easier, not mouse work, but do exactly this:

1. In cell `E2`, enter
   `=FREQUENCY(C2:C724,D2:D37)`. Hit
   <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. You should now be on cell `E3`.
   Press on the **up arrow** once on your
   keyboard to return to `E2` (and it will be **0**).
3. Hold
   down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and press on the **down arrow** until you've
   reached cell `E37`. E2 through E37 will be highlighted.
4. Don't do anything else other than
   hit the <kbd>F2</kbd> key on your
   keyboard now.
5. Now press and hold down
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
   Then, with those two held down, hit
   <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. **Voila!** In every cell between `E2`
   and `E37` you should see this
   `{=FREQUENCY(C2:C724,D2:D37)}` in the formula bar 
   (notice the **{}** brackets) and
   *the formula works*. This is what makes an array formula.

Comment: thank you very much, but it worked the other way as well without the braces

Comment: @I__: that would be impossible for it to work correctly without being an array formula for the example you provided. Here's the online help: http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HP010342543&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL&Version=14&tl=2&queryid=&respos=1&HelpID=xlmain11%2Echm60300

Comment: see the answer below this one, (N8g)'s answer works as well as yours however, he does not answer the question of why it works without braces

Comment: @I__: N8g's produces slightly different results, which isn't an array forumla. If you just put that formula ( `=FREQUENCY(C2:C$724,D2:D37) `) in the first cell and then drag/copy to E37, the numbers will be different. In particular, look at cells E6, E7, E8. Another way to test this, for example, is to replace cell C8 with a value of 12. In Ng8's formula, the 12 bin still only has a value of 3. In the one I listed above, the 12 bin now has a value of 4 (Ctrl+Z to undo this change) because the formula in Ng8's E10 is `=FREQUENCY(C10:C$724,D10:D45)`, which doesn't check above D10 for values.

Comment: @I__: Is there anything else I can help answer for you regarding `FREQUENCY`?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like what you've done is tried to copy and paste the function from the first cell to each of the subsequent cells.

Because it's an array function, what you need to do is:

1. Copy the text of the first cell (from the formula bar)
2. Select all the cells you are wanting the results to appear in
3. Paste the text you just copied into the formula bar
4. Press ctrl-shift-enter

This will put the same array function into all the cells

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what you mean but it sounds like you need to use absolute addressing, prefix the column with $

Answer (score 1):

You need to use absolute reference for the second argument only =FREQUENCY(C2:C$724,D2:D37)